# Javascript - Call function when clicking on a svg shape.

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to do some kind of screen keyboard. When I click on a square it will write a specific letter on a textarea.

I want to call a javascript function everytime I press a new square (and write a new letter).

Using the real computer keyboard I would use "keyup". But here it's not working (neither is "mouseup").

Small demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/bcorreia/oq0sgk8g/

Thank you

HTML

```
<svg width="60px" height="60px">

<rect width="50" height="50" onclick="getElementById('text').value+='a'">
</svg>

<svg width="60px" height="60px">
    <rect width="50" height="50" onclick="getElementById('text').value+='b'">
</svg>

<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $("#text").keyup(function() { 
        console.log("test");
    });
});
```

Comment: It's working with keyup (with my real keyboard) not my screen keyboard...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the way you're implementing this a bit. Instead of using a different inline click event handlers for each rectangle, delegate a single click event programmatically to all rectangles. To differentiate which character should be appended, you can add data attributes to your rectangles that contain the character they represent and retrieve their values in the click handler. To handle physical keyboard input, you have a separate event binding specifically for that. Here's a working example of how I would approach this, with some comments for clarification on what it's doing.

```js
    function yourOtherFunction(input) {
         console.log('You typed a "' + input + '"');   
    }
    
    $(function() {
        // Handle on-screen keyboard clicks (only on rects with a data-character
        // attribute present)
        $('svg rect[data-character]').click(function() {
            // Retrieve the "data-character" attribute value
            var character = $(this).data('character');
            // Modify the value of the textarea by appending the character
            $('#text').val(function(i, old) { return old + character; });
            // Call your other function
            yourOtherFunction(character);
        });

        // Handle physical keyboard key presses:
        $('#text').keypress(function(e) {
            // Retrieve the character representation of the event's key code
            var character = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
            // Call your other function
            yourOtherFunction(character);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <svg width="60px" height="60px">
        <rect width="50" height="50" data-character="a" />
    </svg>
    <svg width="60px" height="60px">
        <rect width="50" height="50" data-character="b" />
    </svg>
        
    <textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

Comment: Can I have the svg in a file and the js script in a different file?

Comment: You *should* have your JavaScript in a separate file; that's always good practice (notice that my markup no longer has any inline JavaScript). Your SVG markup can go wherever you'd like it as long as whatever technology you're using outputs it correctly. Vague answer, but you haven't tagged your question with any server side technologies that might garner a better answer.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not working properly. I click in the rects and it's not writing. 
I believe I'm doing it right. I have keyboard.php and I include it in my index.php. And in my index php I have also my javascript.

Comment: Did you try running my code snippet (the "Run code snippet" button)? It works fine here. Did you include the jQuery library in your page?

Comment: Oh I forgot to change the 'svg rect' to 'svg path'. Thank you very much for your time!